# ValueError when attempting to parse JSON

Tags: python, json

I use Python 3.4 and have to parse JSON like this

```
[['A', 'B', 1.3750], ['X', 'Y', 0.7097]]
```

and I try to use json module, json.loads function to parse it into python object, but I get

```
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

So, what can I do to parse this JSON?

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. Check it at http://jsonlint.com/ and dont try to parse it before it's valid JSON

Comment: This is what web API returns me, what is used in JavaScript, so I have to deal with this somehow.

Comment: You should contact whoever made the API and inform then that in JSON you use " quotes and not ' quotes.

Comment: Whatever web API it is, it's bad. You should either use a different API if possible, or have the code altered so it returns valid JSON

Comment: it looks like someone did `str(list_of_lists)` instead of `json.dumps(list_of_lists)` i.e., you see a string representation of a list in Python instead of a JSON text. Until the API is fixed, you could use `result = ast.literal_eval(broken_input_text)` to parse the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings in JSON require double quotes, not single quotes.

Changing the input to look like this parses using Python 2.7:

```
[["A", "B", 1.3750], ["X", "Y", 0.7097]]
```

**Edit:** After seeing your comment, you'll need to do some string manipulation (e.g., replacing all single-quotes with double-quotes) on the data received from the web API in order to make it into valid JSON.

Comment: @adontz you should still inform the owner of the API that the data it returns is not valid or everyone who uses it will run into this issue

Comment: I already did, but it's bank, they do not care, to be honest.

Comment: @adontz: In that case it's name and shame time.

Comment: @adontz - At the very least ask the bank what "JSON" library they're using which allows single quotes for strings. If they rolled one themselves tell them that's *extremely* insecure and a bank should know better.

Answer (score 0):

it is not valid json but valid literal python you can parse it by using ast.literal_eval

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval("[['A', 'B', 1.3750], ['X', 'Y', 0.7097]]")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two main problems:

- The root item isn't an object
- Strings are delimited with single, rather than double quotes.

If you really want to parse that as JSON, you'll have to do some cleaning first. For example:

```
import json

json_input = "[['A', 'B', 1.3750], ['X', 'Y', 0.7097]]"

print json.loads('{"value": %s}' % json_input.replace("'", '"') )['value']
```

The problem with this is it's very fragile, as the source could send something like `"'"` and it would be converted to `'''` which would cause problems. If you go too far down the route of trying to fix this, you are basically writing a parser again.